# Mocking throwing mongoDb exceptions in Clojure

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, exception, clojure, mocking

I want to overwrite my function to throw com.mongodb.MongoException$DuplicateKey. But that class needs some object called com.mongodb.CommandResult in its constructor.

Problem is with that com.mongodb.CommandResult. No matter what I am trying to do, I end up with:

> No matching ctor found for class com.mongodb.CommandResult

getConstructors says it has no constructor. But if I try to do it without parameters it's the same... Could someone point what am I doing wrong?

I really doubt it, but maybe this will be somehow helpful to understand my problem:

```
user=> (com.mongodb.CommandResult.)

CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching ctor found for class
com.mongodb.CommandResult, compiling:(/tmp/form-init5865306652286645706.clj:1:1)
```

Comment: Did you [import](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/import) the class?

Comment: If I didn't, it would cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `getConstructors` returns nothing, it means there are no public constructors and you cannot create an instance via regular means. You can use [`getDeclaredConstructors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructors%28%29) to access non-public constructors.

Before you do that though, I would suggest an alternative approach: Wrap the MongoDB client in a thin custom wrapper which a) only exposes what you need from the client, b) uses your domain-specific operation names, c) doesn't use any MongoDB-specific types on its surface (catches exceptions, propagates different results than the CommandResult etc.) It's usually much much easier to mock in your tests, can be used to hide hard-to-test APIs, and if it's thin enough, it's reasonably safe not to unit-test the wrapper itself. Integration tests or other higher-level automated tests usually simulate and cover these kinds of errors states quite well.

Comment: Cutting off from Mongo is surely good aproach. But I don't like idea of making integration test per every faulty situation. Instead of throwing exception I will have to go through whole scenario (or maybe it is good thing).
I would like to test that wrapper - "if it's duplicateKey return 1, if networkProblem return 2" giving real exceptions. Is there any way?

Comment: I haven't used the Java/Clojure MongoDB client, but it looks like it's not very mock-friendly. Mocking it should be possible if you use the non-public constructors, but IMO it would be less painful to have minimalistic faulty scenarios for integration testing rather than to have your unit tests rely on implementation details of a 3rd party library - it sounds fragile and the amount of code to make all the mocks/fakes/results may be larger than the whole integration test. It's up to you if it's worth it in your case.

Comment: I was looking for any other solution. Tried to get piece of code that will create exception (some factory). But I failed. In that particular example I guess there is no better solution.
I will do as  you suggested - make thin wrapper-translator.
And will test it with thin integration test, where I'll test just that wrapper by provoking faulty situation. (with some dose of humor you can call it Unit Test :) )